# Global bookmarks stack in Sublime Text 2 (or 3)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I know I can jump between bookmarks in one file by hitting <kbd>F2</kbd>. Is it possible to do it on a project level (in between files)?

What about plugins? Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Bookmarks package https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sublime%20Bookmarks is what you're looking for I think.
Works with ST2 and ST3.

Comment: I stopped using Sublime Text shortly after asking this question, so I'll leave verifying answer to an occasional reader. From the description of the plugin it seem to do exactly what I was looking for.